# Docker Compose: Allowing Network Interactions Between Services

Tags: python, macos, docker, networking, docker-compose

I'd like to have two Docker `containers`, which are defined in the same `docker-compose.yaml` file to be able to share a `network` and interact with each others' exposed ports. I'm running all of this on Docker for Mac.

In order to do so, I've set up a couple docker containers that are running a tiny [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) server which can either return a "Hello" or make a request to another server (see below for details). So far, I've been unable to allow the two apps to communicate with each other.

What I've tried so far:

- `expose`ing the relevant ports
- `publish`ing the ports and mapping them 1:1 with the host
- For `flask` using both `localhost` and `0.0.0.0` as the --host arg
- `curl` from one container to another (using both `localhost:<other_container_port>` and `0.0.0.0:<other_container_port>`
- Using the implicit `network` as per the docs
- Explicit `network` definition

All of the above examples give me a `Connection Refused` error, so I feel like I'm missing something basic about Docker networking.

The [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) doc mentions the following:

> When you run docker-compose up, the following happens:
>
> ...
>
> 3. A container is created using db’s configuration. It
>      joins the network myapp_default under the name db.

And their example appears to have all the separate services be able to communicate without any network definitions, which leads me to believe that I probably should not need to define a network either.

Below is my docker-compose.yaml file - all the files can be found at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/funseiki/12a0cc9c32e6b8aab31cb0d1a6f0f7eb):

```
version: '3'
services:
    receiver:
        build: ./app
        # Tried with/without expose
        expose:
            - 3000
        # Tried with/without ports
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        # Tried with/without 0.0.0.0
        command: "--host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000"
        # Tried with/without explicit network
        networks:
          - mine
    requester:
        build: ./app
        expose:
            - 4000
        ports:
            - 4000:4000
        # This one's ip is 0.0.0.0, so we can access from host
        command: "--host 0.0.0.0 --port 4000"
        networks:
          - mine
networks:
  mine: {}
```

The app.py file:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from {}".format(request.host)

@app.route("/request/<int:port>")
def doPing(port):
     location = "http://localhost:{}/".format(port)
     return requests.get(location, timeout=5).content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in docker-compose the services that are on same network can access each other by its name, you dont even have to expose the ports to host. so your docker-compose.yaml can be simplified to:

```
version: '3'
services:
receiver:
    build: ./app
    command: "--host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000"
requester:
    build: ./app
    command: "--host 0.0.0.0 --port 4000"
```

and inside the container requester you can access the other one with

```
ping receiver
```

that resolves the name and you can verify the port is also open, for example with `netcat`

```
nc -z receiver 3000 -v
```

Comment: but if you want to access the app from your host (mac), you will have to map the ports

Comment: Yep, tried that just before you posted and now I feel silly. Thanks for the quick reply! Didn't realize the expose and publish commands weren't necessary, though, that definitely simplifies things.